# Program stops after starting to enter third information

Tags: c++

/*This starts but gives me an error message from windows saying it stopped working and couldn't find an answer, the attempted run looks like:

```
Enter your stock information.
Company name #1: target
Company symbol #1: tgt
Price per share #1$ 63.39
Shares purchased #1: 456
Company name #2: walmart
Company symbol #2: wmt
Price per share #2$ 73.40
Shares purchased #2: 254
Company name #3: kroger

--------------------------------
Process exited with return value 255
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I don't know why it isn't working, help is appreciated.
*/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

struct StockInfo{
    string compName;
    string compSymbol;
    double pricePer;
    int shares;
};

void getData(StockInfo *);
void displayData(StockInfo *);

int main() {

    StockInfo *stocks;
    stocks = new StockInfo[3];

    getData(stocks);

    displayData(stocks);

    delete [] stocks;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
void getData(StockInfo *stocks){

    cout<< "Enter your stock information."<< endl;

    for(int index = 0; index < 3; index++){
        cout<< "Company name #"<< index + 1<< ": ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.clear();
        cin>> stocks[index + 1].compName;
        cout<< "Company symbol #"<< index + 1<< ": ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.clear();
        cin>> stocks[index + 1].compSymbol;
        cout<< "Price per share #"<< index + 1<< "$ ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.clear();
        cin>> stocks[index + 1].pricePer;
        cout<< "Shares purchased #"<< index + 1<< ": ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.clear();
        cin>> stocks[index + 1].shares;
    }
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}

void displayData(StockInfo *stocks){

    cout<< "***********************************************\n";
    cout<< "*************My Stock Information**************\n";

    for(int count = 1; count <= 3; count++){

        double tot = 0.00;

        tot = stocks[count].pricePer * stocks[count].shares;

        cout<< setprecision(2)<< endl;
        cout<< setw(20)<< left<< "Company Name:"<< setw(20)<< right<<                     stocks[count].compName<< endl;
        cout<< setw(20)<< left<< "Company Symbol:"<< setw(20)<< right<< stocks[count].compSymbol<< endl;
        cout<< setw(20)<< left<< "Share Price:"<<" $"<< setw(20)<< right<< stocks[count].pricePer<< endl;
        cout<< setw(20)<< left<< "Shares:"<< setw(20)<< right<<     stocks[count].shares<< endl;
        cout<< setw(20)<< left<< "Total:"<<" $"<< setw(20)<< right<< tot<< endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: So have you tried running it in a debugger, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading into `stocks[index + 1]` which overflows the array dimensions. You loop from `0` to `2` including, which is correct, but `stocks[index + 1]` tries to access `stocks[3]` when `i == 2`, which is an "index out of bounds" error.

I guess this is a copy & paste problem, since you want to instruct the user to enter data for "#1", "#2" and "#3".

Try this:

```
for(int index = 0; index < 3; index++){
    cout<< "Company name #"<< index + 1<< ": ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.clear();
    cin>> stocks[index].compName;
    cout<< "Company symbol #"<< index + 1<< ": ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.clear();
    cin>> stocks[index].compSymbol;
    cout<< "Price per share #"<< index + 1<< "$ ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.clear();
    cin>> stocks[index].pricePer;
    cout<< "Shares purchased #"<< index + 1<< ": ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.clear();
    cin>> stocks[index].shares;
}
```

Comment: Ah, Yes! You're very correct with the fix suggested. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The main error in your code is because you were trying to access an element in the array that was not there.

```
stocks[index + 1]
```

Remember that an array starts from [0] and on. In your case, when you entered the for loop in the getData function, you were accessing the "second" element in the array, not the "first" by doing [index+1]. 
This means that the 1st element ([0]) was initialized to a garbage value and when the loop entered the final loop, you were essentially trying to access an element of the array that does not exist.

Here is your example working:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct StockInfo
{
    string compName;
    string compSymbol;
    double pricePer;
    int shares;
};


void getData(StockInfo *stocks)
{
    cout<< "Enter your stock information."<< endl;

    for(int index = 0; index < 3; index++)
    {
        cout<< "Company name #"<< index + 1<< ": ";
        cin.clear();
        cin>> stocks[index].compName;
        cout<< "Company symbol #"<< index + 1<< ": ";
        cin.clear();
        cin>> stocks[index].compSymbol;
        cout<< "Price per share #"<< index + 1<< "$ ";
        cin.clear();
        cin>> stocks[index].pricePer;
        cout<< "Shares purchased #"<< index + 1<< ": ";
        cin.clear();
        cin>> stocks[index].shares;
    }
}

void displayData(StockInfo *stocks)
{
    cout<< "***********************************************\n";
    cout<< "*************My Stock Information**************\n";

    for(int count = 0; count < 3; count++)
    {
        double tot = 0.00;

        tot = stocks[count].pricePer * stocks[count].shares;

        cout<< setprecision(2)<< endl;
        cout<< setw(20)<< left<< "Company Name:"    << setw(20) << right    << stocks[count].compName   << endl;
        cout<< setw(20)<< left<< "Company Symbol:"  << setw(20) << right    << stocks[count].compSymbol << endl;
        cout<< setw(20)<< left<< "Share Price:"     << " $"     << setw(20) << right                    << stocks[count].pricePer<< endl;
        cout<< setw(20)<< left<< "Shares:"          << setw(20) << right    << stocks[count].shares     << endl;
        cout<< setw(20)<< left<< "Total:"           <<" $"      << setw(20) << right<< tot              << endl;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    StockInfo *stocks = new StockInfo[3];

    getData(stocks);

    displayData(stocks);

    delete [] stocks;
}
```

Be aware that when using namespaces can and WILL create collision errors with other functions with a similar name, if you are not careful. I would advise you used std::string,
std::cout and so on. It's safer!

Also, have you considered using template containers? Your example is simple enough for you to use arrays, but still won't harm you to know better ways. (std::vector< > is essentially a dynamic array but also clears the memory for you. It will also compute the size of your array and you won't have to hard-code the size in every function ex.3 )

Hope this helps!